# Flutter Image not fitting to column or sized box

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I am using the pub dev packaged [introduction_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen) and I am having issues styling the different pages.

```
      title: "",
      bodyWidget: SizedBox(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/FAQ/logo.png',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

I would think it would fit the sized box but it goes outside of the sized box and does not auto scale to the phones screen size.

I have tried also setting the sizedBox width to `double.infinity` but that didn't help either.

Comment: I tried using MediaQuery.of(context).size.width for the width of the sized box but that did not work either. 

I then added MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; for thte mage width and that was still 32 pixels over...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are having Column with Row as children. As you may know Column can have unbounded height and Row can have unbounded width, using both of them as an ancestor of your widget give unbounded height and width to the widget.

I would suggest you to either use

1. Stack or Centre widget instead of Column/Row combo as ancestor of Image.asset or
2. Use Column -> [Expanded -> Row -> [Expanded -> Image.asset]] in case you have other widget. You can position widgets according to your requirement.